# modify width of processing div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this div that appears on loading pages:

```
<div id="divProcessing" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: transparent;  z-Index: 2000;overflow:hidden; display:none;border:none;"/>
```

My problem is that on a page that has scroll bars the div is not expanded on all the page, only on screen size and i can access the content behind the div if i scroll.

I don't know how to expand or how to calculate the width/height of content page

Comment: what about position:fixed ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/position#Fixed_positioning ..for ie < 7 there are some ways to fix it ;)

Comment: Why do you want this div to cover all the content?

Answer (score 0):

If the `div` is a direct child of `body`, you can try adding:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;     /* in case your content is floated */
}
```

Do you have a page online where we can see it?

Answer (score 0):

I would use jquery, and you can get the height of the body element.

```
$(body).css('height');
```

So you could then do the following:

```
$('#divProcessing').css('height', $(body).css('height') );
```

Which then sets your div's height to the same as the body of your page.

Edit: You mentioned width specifically but I was thinking height, the same will work for width, just replace 'height' with 'width'